# Does UNION in MySQL depend on the order of "SELECT"?

Tags: mysql, union

I have two sql requests. The first request is:

```
SELECT field_1, field_2
FROM mydb.table_1, mydb.table_2
WHERE TIME > 0 
  AND TIME <= 1460539620031 
  AND table_1_id = table_1.id 
UNION
SELECT field_1, field_2 
FROM mydb.table_1, mydb.table_3
WHERE TIME > 0 
  AND TIME <= 1460539620031 
  AND table_1_id = table_1.id;
```

and the second request is:

```
SELECT field_1, field_2
FROM mydb.table_1, mydb.table_3
WHERE TIME > 0 
  AND TIME <= 1460539620031 
  AND table_1_id = table_1.id 
UNION
SELECT field_1, field_2 
FROM mydb.table_1, mydb.table_2
WHERE TIME > 0 
  AND TIME <= 1460539620031 
  AND table_1_id = table_1.id;
```

They differ only in the order of commands "SELECT", but the command "SELECT" are the same. But the results of executing these requests are different: **the first resultset contains more rows than the other**.

Why is it happaning? Does UNION in MySQL depend on the order of "SELECT"?

Comment: Without explicit **`ORDER BY`** order of resultset is not guaranteed. Period.

Comment: Shouldn't make any difference

Comment: @lad2025 I don't think that was the question, i think he meant if `table1,table3 union table1,table2` equals `table1,table2 union table1,table3`

Comment: @sagi, I also thought so, but in practice there is difference...

Comment: @Ksenia The fact that one of this select returns the output faster doesn't say anything, it only fetches some of the rows so maybe one of the selects are slightly faster, but to select all records it should take the same time.. Try wrapping them both in `CREATE TABLE test AS(....)` , that you can compare the differences(if any)

Comment: @lad2025, yes, sagi was right, it isn't the question

Comment: @Ksenia Please probive http://sqlfiddle.com to recreate your case.

Comment: No, the differenct isn't in order or speed, the first resultset contains more rows than the other.

Comment: @Ksenia Will you provide demo or your **real queries**?

Comment: @lad2025, it will be complicated, the database has complex structure

Comment: So probably this is the case. In your sample code it shouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because SQLyog (where I run queries) added the expression "LIMIT 0, 10000" to the end of the queries.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the result of a union is in the order or unions. However, union remove duplicates and to so, it needs to sort things internally (or equivalent). It is probable that the order of the unions has an impact on this remove duplicate phase and it most case it might looks like the row are produced in order of the statements.

Taken from the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

> However, use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows.

In other, the order is not guarantee. If you want a specific order you need to add some parenthesis and put an order clause at the end.

If you really want to have the result groupeb by table, you could have a look at the solution within the documentation.

> To cause rows in a UNION result to consist of the sets of rows retrieved by each SELECT one after the other, select an additional column in each SELECT to use as a sort column and add an ORDER BY following the last SELECT:

```
(SELECT 1 AS sort_col, col1a, col1b, ... FROM t1)
UNION
(SELECT 2, col2a, col2b, ... FROM t2) ORDER BY sort_col;
```